# 2 internal calls error when launching application

Tags: android, view, navigation

i am trying to implement navigationbar dloating button an menu items in navbar in a blank activity...each layout is independently creatly in xml an then instantiated in main activity..before this there was an error class coul not be found i cleared it .. in drawable folder there 6 icons from meterial esign so they are not taking too much space .. i cleared all the errors but now i cant get past this one says "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"....apart from this there is this error " Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 2internal calls"
here is the complete logcat:
07-20 12:49:19.875 24515-24515/com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    Process: com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar, PID: 24515
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar/com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                at com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:209)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:122)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:250)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:174)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
07-20 12:49:24.750 24515-24515/com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24515 SIG: 9




   MAIN ACTIVITY: 
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with yor own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            assert drawer != null;
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navbar);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else
                super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_explore) {
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_explore) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_playlist) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_album) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_video) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_songs) {

            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;


        }
    }
main_activity xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.navbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/appbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_bar"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

appbar xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email">

    </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

navbar header xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Music Player"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It clearly tells to check your line #16 of your xml file

Comment: you inflating wrong NavigationView. attch your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct for binding views, so in this case you are OK to go binding of views. You should consider checking the layouts used for **NavigationView.**

There must be some issue in layouts you referenced in NavigationView.
i.e.

```
 app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_bar"
 app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
```

Comment: thanks alot it helped .. the problem was in menu root tag was not appropriate !